# Granting guest access to server with key based SSH login

Tags: authentication, ssh

Quite simple: How can guest SSH access to a server be granted to multiple users who will share the same 'guest' login?

The server has only RSA key access (no password login) and this works fine for the normal case where the public keys of single users are copied to authorized_keys on the remote server.  What I'm looking for is guest access as user 'guest', the problem is the keys - I don't want to have to install keys from all my clients, rather give them a key to use - would this be the private 'guest' key?  How does this work?

Clients will be connecting from Linux, and Windows using Putty.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a problem here. 
In your setup you treat all connecting people as a single person. Thus they all can use the same key, in this case you have to hand out the private key to all of them. 
However that is a BIG security risk. Once that key is given out (happens with lots of unexperienced users) you have to replace the keys for ALL people. That does not sound very good.

Comment: Thanks for the response, much as I'd assumed and doesn't sound like an elegant solution.  The 'guest' login lands in a chrooted jail, so not a complete disaster from a security perspective, but as you say, far from ideal.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is reverse the procedure.

Create the RSA keys at server side. And then copy public key to the `authorized_keys` file and take private key at client side.

So now multiple clients can do ssh to the server using this private key.